# How to include longitudinal information in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, panel-data, binary-data

I have a binary outcome $y_i \in \{0,1\}$, $i=1,\dots,n$, and some covariates $x_i\in{\mathbb R}^p$. I am planning to model these using a logistic regression model.

However, I also have information from a period of time before $y_i$ was observed at time points $t_1,\dots,t_{m_i}$. This longitudinal information is basically another set of covariates $z_i(t_j)\in{\mathbb R}^q$ that are measured at the times $t_1,\dots,t_{m_i}$. How can I include the longitudinal information into my logistic regression model?

Comment: So do you have time series data then? Are the time points correlated?

Comment: @user2974951 Yes, i have a multivariate time series with continuous and categorical variables. The points are correlated in the sense that they correspond to the same items, like in longitudinal studies.

Comment: Then maybe a logistic mixed model.